# Angular velocity of a coordinate system in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, differential-geometry, angular-velocity

In the textbook, [The Classical Theory of Fields (Landau & Lifshitz)](http://www.elegio.it/mc2/LandauLifshitz_TheClassicalTheoryOfFields_text.pdf), the authors express the line interval of the 3-dimensional absolute-space in the form
$$dl^2=\gamma_{\alpha\beta}dx^\alpha dx^\beta$$ where $$\gamma_{\alpha\beta}=\left(-g_{\alpha\beta}+\frac{g_{0\alpha}g_{0\beta}}{g_{00}}\right)$$
corresponding to the line interval of the 4-dimensional space-time $ds^2=g_{ik}dx^idx^k$. Then, they define a 3-dimensional vector $\mathbf{g}$ as
$$g_\alpha=-\frac{g_{0\alpha}}{g_{00}}$$
In Problem 1 (after Section $\S88$) in the textbook, the authors calculate the force acting on a particle in a constant gravitational field, and they obtain a Coriolis-like force that would act if the coordinate system is rotating with an angular velocity
$$\mathbf{\Omega}=\frac{c}{2}\sqrt{g_{00}}\:(\mathrm{curl}\:\mathbf{g})$$

**I couldn't understand the physical interpretation of this angular velocity. Can we derive this formula of $\mathbf{\Omega}$ from the space-time metric tensor $g_{ik}$?**

**It would be extremely helpful if someone could provide some references where detailed calculation are performed.**

NOTE: The index $\alpha,\beta=1,2,3$ and the index $i,k=0,1,2,3$ (according to the textbook.)

Comment: I don't have answer, I have a similar question Ive been trying to resolve. The content starting at page 50 at this link, https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS4160/v05/undervisningsmateriale/kompendium.pdf  might be helpful.